# SQL query that concatenates values from duplicate rows in a single table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, aggregate

Let's say I have a table of `employees`, like this:

```
Name     Sex     Role

Bob      M       Developer
Joe      M       QA
```

Now, I have a problem with duplicated rows in this table. I will fix it sometime but it's not the issue. What I currently need is something that queries such a table:

```
Name     Sex     Role

Bob      M       Developer
Bob      M       Janitor
Joe      M       QA
Joe      M       CEO
```

And will output the following rows:

```
Name     Role

Bob      Developer, Janitor
Joe      QA, CEO
```

It doesn't matter to me if the "Role" will be split to separate columns or be a single column with multiple values.

Using SQL Server 2008 if it matters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Group_concat as in MySQL is not available in SQL Server up to SQL Server 2016. vNext will introduce [`STRING_AGG`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx) however that provides equivalent functionality.

You have some manual options though:

- build a scalar function that takes an employee name/id as parameter and shows concatenated role values and apply this function to each employee
- use xml functions
- use an [already built aggregate](http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/) (similar as first option)

A solution for your current case (just took Brad's answer from SO and customized for your table) would be:

```
SELECT name, LEFT(roles , LEN(roles )-1) AS roles
FROM employee AS extern
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT role + ','
    FROM employee AS intern
    WHERE extern.name = intern.name
    FOR XML PATH('')
) pre_trimmed (roles)
GROUP BY name, roles;
```

These details are gathered from different sources:

- [Simulating group_concat MySQL function in MS SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005) - on StackOverflow.com
- [Emulating MySQL’s GROUP_CONCAT() Function in SQL Server 2005](http://blog.shlomoid.com/2008/11/emulating-mysqls-groupconcat-function.html) - blog
- [GROUP_CONCAT in SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2010/06/21/group_concat-in-sql-server/) - blog
- [T-SQL Equivalent For Group_Concat() Function](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/f09d4166-2030-41fe-b86e-392fbc94db53) - MSDN

Answer (score -1):

I would try it with the following, but please be aware, that this can run quite a time on very big tables.

```
select a.name, a.role, b.role from employees a, employees b where a.name=b.name and a.role<>b.role
```

I called the table "employees" and the columns "name" and "role".

Comment: Will there ever be 3 roles?

Comment: Also, added to gbn's question, this doesn't give a correct answer, it will return: [bob, janitor, developer] and also [bob, developer, janitor].